# Remove characters with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am not a regex specialist, so I need some help with this.
I have a text file, and I need to remove some trailing delimiters.
The text file looks like this:

```
MSH|^~\&|OAZIS||||20101029135359||ADT^A31|00000015|P|2.3.1||||||ASCII
EVN|A31|20101029135359^^^^||||19900101
```

So I think the best way is to do a Regex replace?
Can anyone help me with this regex?

I want to remove all `^` that come before a `|`

So `test^A^^|` has to become `test^A|`

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\^+\|", "|");
```

should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

I belive your regular expression would look like this...

```
\^+\|
```

That should match one ore more '^' followed by a '|'.

Answer (score 1):

The regex to match will be something like :

> ^+\|

But its dangerous to use regexes you don't understand (just like any other code !)

read some tutorials or you'll miss a lot of things, for example :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx

Comment: `^` will be interpreted as an anchor.